# Integral of bounded measurable function with convergent sequence of measures.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

I'm stuck on the following problem from Bass's "Real Analysis for Graduate Students" (Exercise 7.21):

Suppose $\mu_n$ is a sequence of measures on $(X,\mathcal{A})$ such that $\mu_n(X)=1$ for all $n$ and $\mu_n(A)$ converges as $n\to\infty$ for each $A\in\mathcal{A}$. Call the limit $\mu(A)$.

(1) Prove that $\mu$ is a measure.

(2) Prove that $\int f\;d\mu_n\to\int f\;d\mu$ whenever $f$ is bounded and measurable.

(3) Prove that $$\int f\;d\mu\le\liminf_{n\to\infty}\int f\;d\mu_n$$ whenever $f$ is non-negative and measurable.

Note that this question is from the chapter that introduces the monotone convergence theorem, Fatou's lemma, and the dominated convergence theorem. I was able to prove (1) fairly easily. However, I'm stuck on (2). I'm trying to show that $$\left|\int f\;d\mu_n-\int f\;d\mu\right|\to0$$ but can't seem to find an appropriate bound. Perhaps it would be better to show that 
$$\int f\;d\mu\le\liminf\int f\;d\mu_n$$
and
$$\limsup\int f\;d\mu_n\le\int f\;d\mu$$
but I doubt the author intended for us to use (3) to prove (2), otherwise he'd switch the order. Any help with (2) or (3) is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that (3) is for $f$ nonnegative not-necessarily bounded above, so you will need something to go from (2) to (3).

For (2), note that it is obviously true for simple functions $f$.  So pick an arbitrary bounded measurable $f$, and squeeze it between two simple functions $u_k$ and $l_k$:
$$
f-2^{-k}\leq l_k\leq f\leq u_k\leq f+2^{-k}
$$
Integrate with respect to $\mu_n$
$$
\int_X l_k\,\mathrm{d}\mu_n\leq\int_X f\,\mathrm{d}\mu_n\leq \int_X u_k\,\mathrm{d}\mu_n
$$
so
$$
\int_X l_k\,\mathrm{d}\mu\leq\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_X f\,\mathrm{d}\mu_n\leq \int_X u_k\,\mathrm{d}\mu
$$
But we also have, by monotonicity of integral,
$$
\int_X l_k\,\mathrm{d}\mu\leq\int_X f\,\mathrm{d}\mu\leq \int_X u_k\,\mathrm{d}\mu
$$
So
$$
\left\lvert\int_X f\,\mathrm{d}\mu-\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_X f\,\mathrm{d}\mu_n\right\rvert\leq\int_X (u_k-l_k)\,\mathrm{d}\mu\leq 2^{1-k}
$$
But $k$ is arbitrary.

Can you see how to use (2) to prove (3)?

Comment: Excellent proof, thank you. I'm afraid I do not see how to use (2) to prove (3). As you mentioned, $f$ is bounded in (2), but not in (3), so I can't see how it applies.

Comment: Since $f$ is not necessarily bounded above, you only get to play with bounding $f$ from below.  Then take limit of integrals (be careful so you get liminf out of this!).

Comment: Got it, thanks for your help.